# Internet connection sharing via WiFi in Windows 10 Home

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I try to follow [this instruction](http://www.howtogeek.com/112050/how-to-turn-your-windows-8-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/) to allow other devices to connect to the Internet via my PC. The goal I want to achieve is:

- My PC connects to the Internet via WiFi, to an SSID say `A`;
- I want to give my phone Internet access by connecting it to my PC via WiFi. In other words, my PC broadcasts an SSID `B` and my phone can simply connect to it to get Internet access; just like when connecting directly to `A`. So my PC will act just like a proxy server. Every web request comes to the PC; the PC makes the request and then forward the traffic to the phone.

In the past, this used to be possible via the *Create ad hoc network* dialog in the *Network and sharing center* but it is nowhere to be found on Windows 10. The instruction I mentioned creates a virtual *LAN connection* on the PC with the correct SSID. But when I tried to connect to it from my phone, it does not work and there is no reason reported from the phone. (On my PC, I just see that there is no client.) Here is the screenshot of the hosted network interface: (apparently the IP are invalid)

[image]

My educated guess is that my PC needs to run some sort of DHCP server to assign IP address to my phone and possibly it also needs some kind of DNS server as well. These could probably be implemented in some system service; but even though I enabled most network services (Network Setup Service, Function Discovery Resource Publication, DNS Client, DHCP Client, etc.), it does not work either so it could be the case that DHCP/DNS server software is no longer included in Windows 10; just like many other features that are present on Windows 7.

So my question is how to make this work or whether I need another edition of Windows 10 and how to troubleshoot these things (network configuration) in general.

Please do not suggest that I just connect my phone directly to the SSID that my PC connects to. I want to know more about how things work.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, hacking and `wireshark`ing, I strongly believe that Windows 10 (Home) indeed does not come with built-in DHCP/DNS server. Without one, there is no way to make use of the hosted network feature unless you are network expert, a programmer and willing to spend hours of reading and coding. *I am now starting to question my decision to jump to Windows 10 at all*. Manually running one such as [this little excellent server](http://www.dhcpserver.de/) allows other devices such as my XBox One to connect like a charm. My phone cannot connect though but considering that my XBox can do that, my suspect is now that it is due to the buggy and incomplete Windows 10 Mobile.